# Torsion on $\pi_1(X)$, $X$ connected and open in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Can the fundamental group of an open connected subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ have a torsion element?

Comment: What happens if we embed, say $SO(3)$ into $\mathbb{R}^9$ and thicken it by a small epsilon to make it open? Is the unthickened *core* a deformation retract of the thickened version?

Answer (score 13):

The real projective plane $\Bbb R P^2$ embeds into $\Bbb R^4$. Taking a tubular neighborhood $N$ of this embedding, we get for all $n \geq 4$ an open subset $N \subset \Bbb R^n$ such that $\pi_1(N) \cong \Bbb Z/2$, so the fundamental group of this open subset has torsion.

For $n = 2$, there is no such subset; see the following article:

> Eda, K. *Free $\sigma$-products and fundamental groups of subspaces of the plane*. Topology and its Applications Volume 84, Issues 1-3, 24 April 1998, pp. 283-306.

This is actually an open problem for $n = 3$.

Comment: I think it's an open problem for compact subsets of $\mathbf{R}^3$, but the answer is certainly known for open subsets (there's no torsion). Indeed start from a torsion loop, and find in your open subset a compact 3-fold containing this loop as well as a homotopy from a power of this loop to the constant. Then you get an orientable compact 3-fold with nonempty boundary with torsion in the fundamental group. From Thurston's geometrization it should be easy to conclude, and probably there's an argument using much less machinery.

Comment: Could somebody tell me how the 2-dimensional case follows from the results in Eda's paper? It seems to deal only with spaces which are the complement of a subset of the x-axis.

Answer (score 5):

As you can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_plane#Embedding_into_4-dimensional_space), the real projective plane $\mathbb{R}P^2$ can be embedded in to $\mathbb{R}^4$ and so, taking a sufficiently small $\epsilon$ open neighbourhood of the image of our embedding, gives a homotopy equivalent surface with fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. This is probably the most simple case.