# The fundamental group of an open set in $\mathbb{R} ^n$ does not have nilpotent elements.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

I am studying a little of basic algebraic topology and I thought that this statement could be true. If you have an open connected set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^m$  and a loop $\gamma$ that is not null-homotopic (homotopic to a constant) then $\gamma \ast \gamma ... \ast \gamma$ (n-times) is never null-homotopic for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: See my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287009/torsion-on-pi-1x-x-connected-and-open-in-mathbbrn/287018#287018

Comment: Is this true for $m \le 3$?

Comment: Henry, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Usually when talking about a group one would say that it has no elements of finite order. Or in a more fancy way that the group is torsion-free.